# Vuejs How To Use Multiple Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I want to use different components for admin panel-website. I try that;

```js
// App.vue
<template>
    <PanelTemplate v-if="$route.meta.template == 'panel'"/>
    <WebsiteTemplate v-if="$route.meta.template == 'website'"/>
</template>

<script>
import PanelTemplate from './templates/PanelTemplate.vue'
import WebsiteTemplate from './templates/WebsiteTemplate.vue'
export default {
    components : {
        PanelTemplate,
        WebsiteTemplate
    }
}
</script>

// Router.js
  {
    path: "/panel/dashboard",
    name : "panel-index",
    component: PanelView,
    meta : { template : 'panel' }
  },
  {
    path : "/",
    name : "website-index",
    component : WebsiteView,
    meta : { template : 'website' }
  },

// PanelTemplate.vue - WebsiteTemplate.vue
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

But that's not working. I try `component tag` too but that's not working too. I am seeing just white screen, both of components not calling. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `router-view` tag should be present in `App.vue` and wrapped by one of the template components:

```html
<template>
    <component :is="currentTemplate">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </component>
</template>

<script>
import PanelTemplate from './templates/PanelTemplate.vue'
import WebsiteTemplate from './templates/WebsiteTemplate.vue'
export default {
    computed:{
     currentTemplate(){
        return this.$route.meta.template
     }
    },
    components : {
        PanelTemplate,
        WebsiteTemplate
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working still just white screen

Comment: The issue is in your template, please add some content inside them rather the router-view tag

Comment: if I use `currentTemplate(){ return 'PanelTemplate' }` it's working what ı want. But when I use `return this.$route.meta.template` not working. I logged it: `console.log(this.$route.meta.template);` otuputs is; first `undefined`, second `PanelTemplate`. It should work but not working.

Comment: Please update this sandbox with your code in order to debug it https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-router-demo?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: I solved when I debugged it. Thank u much

Answer (score 2):

If you want each component to have its own separate template (most common case), just place it as `<template>` tag in the `.vue` file. You don't need to specify it in the route and it doesn't need an identifier.

Example `.vue` file structure (called `SFC` - single file component):

```html
<template>
  /// template here
</template>
<script>
...
</script>
<style>
...
</style>
```

---

If you want to use the same template for multiple components, you could place any number of templates anywhere in your page. Since they need to be available at all times, they could be direct children of `<body>`:

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    ...
  </div>
  <template id="panel-tpl">
    ...panel template content goes here
  </template>
</body>
```

Now you can use this template in as many components as you want, by setting the template property to `#panel-tpl`:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  template: '#panel-tpl',
  // the rest of your component
})
</script>
```

Note: This time, the template needs an identifier. Note the identifier (`id`) has to be unique across all the page's HTML (no other HTML element should have the same `id`).

---

Alternate syntax for template:

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="panel-tpl">
  // template contents here
</script>
```