# Render a view ignoring router template

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I am creating an Admin Dashboard with vitejs, vue3 and vue-router. Exists 2 different templates for all views:

1. Views having a sidebar:

   - /buildings
   - /users
   - /companies
2. View with a full-width where the user can login or signup:

   - /login
   - /signup

Each component is render in the `App.vue` file with a sidebar:

```html
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-6">
    <div class="bg-blue-400">
      <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/buildings">Buildings</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/companies">Companies</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-5">
      <div class="p-10">
        <router-view/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

However, for `/login` view I need to display a different template because there is no reason to display a sidebar with links in a login form. Because both cases differ in template format, how can I use different templates for a unique router but for different views? Many thanks for considering my request.

I have tried [Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes), but I am forced to changing all my routes to uses `children` key, for example:

```json
    // Routes dashboard
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: TemplateWithSidebar, // template 1
        children: [
            {
                path: 'companies',
                component: CompaniesView,
            }
        ]
    },


    // Routes for login
    {
        path: '/l',
        component: TemplateWithoutSidebar, // template 2
        children: [
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginView,
            }
        ]
    },
```

Then my App.vue was changed to:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>

</template>
```

I am not experienced enough to determinates if this practice is valid for a production environment o weather exists another best alternative.

Comment: You can also use "Named Views" https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html. You can have multiple routerviews and use them like slots.

Comment: @Orbis, this is pretty accurate according to the original question.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73110930/4254681)